# Display icons on two or more rows so that each row has equal number of icons

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I have 12 image icons in a raw in divs with `display: inline-block` but when I resize my browser window I want to display icons on two or more rows so that each row has equal number of icons.

Comment: what's this concept of downline-ning?

Comment: What do you mean by downlining?..If you mean you want the divs to appear one for each row..you can remove display:inline-block for them or try display:flex it is responsive too

Comment: It should not be one in a row. It should be all in the same line, but when I resize the browser window I want them to downlining equaly, like 6 on to top and 6 on bottom or 3 on top and 3 on the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you'd like to display icons on two or more rows so that each row has equal number of icons. One way to achieve that is to use percentage widths and breakpoints:

```
.icon {
    width: 33.333%;  // on < 600px display 3 icons on a row
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .icon {
    width: 25%;  // on > 600px display 4 icons on a row
  }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .icon {
    width: 16.666%;  // on > 900px display 6 icons on a row
  }
}
```